# yii2 validate only one input field

Tags: validation, model, yii2

In my model (In yii2 project) I have two columns called **product** and **code**. And the issue is how to validate only **code** not **product**. We know that `$model->validate()` validates entire model. But I need only one input field: **code**. Is it possible??

More clearly, In my input form I'm using 3 models. How to validate these 3 models in my controller. That's why I'm trying to validate fields of each model separalety? I meant to validate like:

`$model->validate(someField)`

`$anotherModel->(anotherField)`

Is this possible??

Comment: You can change that in models rules function.

Comment: Use Yii2 scenario.

Comment: How about this? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttribute()-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this function with model. also show what you have tried so far?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['code', ], 'required'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scenario approach in validations rules, and validate only needed fields, by passing appropriate scenario.

More info about scenarios:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html

Comment: Define one base model and inside set other models like attributes base model. Then when you validate base model extend validate() function and validate ohter models by your needs
`function validate() {
  if (true) {
    $this->model2->scenario = 'my-custom-validation';
    if (!$this->model2->validate()) {
        $this-addError('model2');
    }
  }
}`

Comment: If my second model is **barcode** is this code correct which I added main model class: `public function getBarcode(){
        return $this->hasMany(BarcodeModel::className(), ['u_id' => 'id']);
    }

    function validate() {
        if (true) {
            $this->barcode->scenario = 'barcode-validation';
            if (!$this->barcode->validate()) {
                return $this-addError('barcode');
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: No you have to create your barcode model by your self in constructor or somewhere else. Eg. in base model constructor werite: 
`$this->barcodeModel = new BarcodeModel();`
and then validate that property.

Comment: Now I'm having an error: `Declaration of app\models\CLubsModel::validate() should be compatible with yii\base\Model::validate($attributeNames = NULL, $clearErrors = true)` And it says error is related to ClubsModelSearch()

Comment: In CLubsModel add parameters to function validate($attributeNames = NULL, $clearErrors = true)
This is php programming basics...